# Translation for the word "spoiled": "verzogen"?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, idiomaticity

Which word would you use to translate the English adjective *spoiled*, like in the example:

> He is really a spoiled kid.

Would you recommend using the word *verzogen*? Is that what most people would say? Is it correct?

Comment: Yep, "verzogenes Gör/Blag/Balg" passt gut. Notfalls auch "verzogenes Kind" ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd like to second what [Veredomon](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20225/1224) already said. For reference [see this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verw%C3%B6hntes%20Kind%2C%20verzogenes%20Kind&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverw%C3%B6hntes%20Kind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverzogenes%20Kind%3B%2Cc0).

Note, however, that there's basically a difference between the words *verzogen* and *verwöhnt*:

- *verwöhnt*:
  anspruchsvoll , wählerisch, man weiß viele Dinge nicht mehr zu schätzen
  (hard to please, choosy, you've stopped appreciating little things)
- *verzogen*:
  'falsch' oder 'schlecht' erzogen
  ('wrongly' or 'badly' brought up)

*Verzogen* usually suggests *verwöhnt*, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

*Verwöhntes* or *verzogenes Kind*. I'd say, however, that *verwöhnt* is more common, although it is essentially more neutral. *Verzogen* sounds a little bit dated to me.

Comment: `verwöhnt` ist in dem Kontext sicher keine akkurate Übersetzung, weil es positiv klingt (`spoiled` bedeutet u. A. auch `verdorben`, wenn auch im Kontext von Nahrungsmitteln). Siehe auch https://www.dict.cc/?s=spoiled+brat